# Composite Bands (Data Management)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, multi-band

I am building a small multispectral camera based on the Raspberry Pi Compute Module and two Raspberry Pi cameras. One of the cameras has a NIR filter, the other is a normal RGB camera. 
When using the Composite Bands tool in ArcMap, and mix the bands as to get a falso color image, I got a blue image, rather than red. The combination is NIR, RED, GREEN.[image]

That's the end image.

Any ideas why do I get this blue instead of red color?

Comment: It looks like you do have a false color image! But, I'm guessing you want the typical false color infrared image that shows veg (i.e. chlorophyll). Stupid question: have you tried changing the band order? Try green in the blue slot (slot 1), red in the green slot (slot 2), and NIR in the red slot (slot 3). So basically, ditch the blue, and move all the other bands up a slot. It looks like, since you have NIR in the blue band, it's just being shown as blue.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially as I'm sure you are aware, you are creating a false color composite which is an image that depicts an object in colors that differ from what a true-color image would show. In your false color, you are indicating that you wish for NIR to be displayed as red, red to be displayed as green, and green to be displayed as blue. This combination is actually very good for doing vegetation analysis. I take it that in the original photograph the blue that you now see is actually green? Load the bands differently if you wish for a different desired output. More importantly then why you are getting these colors, is the question of what exactly are you looking for?